# Ardurno PubsubClient Mqtt ESP8266 connection issue on Hive MQ

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I have a HiveMq mqtt broker credential to connect MQTT broker using PubsubClient from Ardurno .. I tried to connect its throwing an error -4 time out.

Hivemq broker url -   xxxxxxx.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud
Username : xxxx
Password : xxxx
Port - 8883
No Certificate
Code - client.connect("client_id",mqtt_username,mqtt_password))

I tried in MQTT explorer its connected because i enabled the Tls option.Attached the screen for your reference. Could some one share the code to enable the Tls on PubsubClient.(Sample code). Note that no certificate. only encription.(Hive does not give certificate)

[Mqtt Explorer][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGzVl.png

Thanks
Murugan

Comment: MQTT has nothing to do with TLS, it is the TCP client that usually setup the TLS, so check WiFi Secure Client on how to setup a secure client.

Comment: Yes you are right. Need a sample code to set encription true.